# Error in SQL Server while adding foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Employee' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key.

I have already set my reference as primary key, but still getting the error.

```
 Create table Employee 
 (
     Fname varchar(20),
     Mint varchar(1),
     Lname varchar(20),
     Ssn int,
     Bdat date,
     [Address] varchar(50),
     Sex varchar(1),
     Salary int,
     Super_ssn int,
     Dno int
)

Create table Department   
(
     Dname varchar(20),
     Dnumber int,
     Mgr_ssn int,
     Mgr_start_date date
)

Alter table Employee
alter column Ssn int NOT NULL
alter column Super_ssn int NOT NULL

alter table Employee
add primary key (Ssn, Super_ssn)

alter table Department 
add foreign key (Mgr_ssn) 
    References Employee (Ssn)
```

Comment: Can you please include a schema (or CREATE TABLE) statements for the tables you are adding the relationship to, as well as the columns you are referencing?

Comment: Alright @ArtjomB. Edited the question

Comment: Side note: `varchar(1)` is pretty pointless - it will use 2-3 bytes of storage for storing at most 1 character. For short string, you should use `char(1)` - that only takes exactly 1 byte and will happily store your entire character - or NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a composite PK in your Employees table (`Ssn, Super_ssn`), but you try to reference it with one column (`Mgr_ssn`).

Either change the PK to `Ssn` only, or add another column to the foreign key.